# Using Beautiful Soup, grabbing stuff between <li> and </li>

Tags: python, html, tags, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

lis = []
webpage = urllib.urlopen('http://facts.randomhistory.com/interesting-facts-about-     cats.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
for ul in soup:
    for li in soup.findAll('li'):
        lis.append(li)
    for li in lis:
        print li.text.encode("utf-8")
```

I'm just trying to get the cat facts from between the opening and closing "li" tags and output them in a way that doesn't look messed up. Currently, the output from this code repeats all of the facts 4 times or so and the word "can't" comes out as "canâ€™t".

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you iterating through the `ul` elements then not using them? Get rid of that `for` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `Content-Type` says its encoding is `ISO-8859-1`, but it is lying. Tell Beautiful Soup to ignore its lies using `from_encoding`. You can make Beautiful Soup do less work by giving it a `SoupStrainer` for `parse_only` that selects only things with the `content-td` class. Finally, you can simplify your `for` loops. All together:

```
import urllib2
import bs4

webpage = urllib2.urlopen('http://facts.randomhistory.com/interesting-facts-about-cats.html')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, from_encoding='UTF-8',
                         parse_only=bs4.SoupStrainer(attrs='content-td'))
for li in soup('li'):
    print li.text.encode('utf-8')
```

You can further improve the output by replacing consecutive whitespace with a single space and removing the superscripts.

Comment: This is working for me, but i'm still getting â€™ instead of apostrophes.

Comment: @user2256199: I don't know what to say about that; the `from_encoding` fixes everything for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the outer loop (`for ul in soup`).  It will output once if you remove it.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
for li in soup.findAll('li'):
    lis.append(li)
for li in lis:
    print li.text.encode("utf-8")
```